# How to get data from select field Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Hi everyone i have problem. I need to take data from Select field filled by entity class.

This is my entity: It's dictionary with months and first and last day.

**Entity**

```
namespace accountant\ReportBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Calendar
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="month", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $month;
}
```

I load fixtures to this table to db and create formBuilder:

**FormType**

```
class ReportFormType extends AbstractType
{
     public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('month','entity', array(
                'class' => 'ReportBundle:Calendar',
                'property' => 'month',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false
            ));
    }
}
```

Now I want to get data from selected month to, but `$data` is `null`:

**Controller**

```
 /**
 * @Route("/report", name="report")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ReportFormType());
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $data = $form->getData();

    var_dump($data);    // $data is null!       

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

**TWIG**

```
<form method="get" action="{{ path('report') }}">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_row(form.month, {'label': 'Select Month:', 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Show Report" class="btn btn-warning btn-block"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

**UPDATE 1**

I add 'data_class' but i still get NULL.

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('month','entity', array(
            'class' => 'ReportBundle:Calendar',
            'choice_label' => 'month',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
        ));
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
   $resolver->setDefaults(array(
       'data_class' => Calendar::class
   ));
}
```

This is my Controller now.

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ReportFormType());
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $data = $form->get('month')->getData();
    // i check data
    var_dump($data);

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView());
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I solved my problem i change my form in template for this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('report') }}" novalidate="novalidate">
{{ form_errors(form) }}
<div class="form-group">
{{ form_row(form.month, {'label': 'Select month', 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
{{ form_rest(form) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Show report" class="btn btn-warning btn-block"/>
</div>
```

I change method to `post` and add `form_rest`

Comment: You need to configure data_class on the main form.

Comment: Your Symfony version ?

Comment: @Trix 2.7 and 7.2.7 php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your form like :

```
use accountant\ReportBundle\Entity\Calendar;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ReportFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('month','entity', array(
                'class' => 'ReportBundle:Calendar',
                'property' => 'month',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => false
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'=> Calendar::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Keep in mind to have first letter of namespace sections in CAPS (`Accountant` instead of `accountant`).

## Update

According to OP's comment, you may get `month` data in your controller:

**Symfony 2**

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...

    $data = $form->get('month')->getData();

    // ...
}
```

**Symfony 3 & 4**

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...

    $data = $form['month']->getData();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I add 'data_class' but i still get NULL

Comment: Please check the **Update**

Comment: I have that before. I found this in documentaction: https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/forms.html , but still NULL.